# Parallel and Series Oscillator in Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electric-circuits, oscillators

In the electrical domain two types of (damped) oscillator exists:

- series oscillator: coil, capacitor and resistor are connected in series; the current through each element is the same and the voltages add up $u_{in} = u_C + u_L + u_R$
- parallel oscillator: coil, capacitor and resistor are parallel connected; the voltage over each element is the same and the currents add up $i_{in} = i_C + i_L + i_R$

In the mechanical domain a damped mass spring system is similar to the parallel oscillator in the sense that the forces add up $F_{in} = F_m + F_k + F_d$. My question now is: can a system like a mechanical series oscillator exist where there is only one force i.e. the input force $F_{in} $ acting in the system? I think this question might be related to bond graph theory, but I could not come up with a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange mechanical elements in parallel or in series just as you can electrical ones.

There is formal way to translate mechanical circuits into electrical ones (and vice versa). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies